# What's the difference between "Which {buses / are the buses / buses are} go near my office"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is the correct sentence construction? And why?

1) Which are the buses go near my office?

2) Which buses go near my office?

3) which buses are go near my office?

as per my knowledge, the first sentence gives an idea about someone asking about regularly plying buses. Asking about truth or routinely plying buses

And the second sentence means just asking about bus routes

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Which are the buses **that** go near my office? *- OK*
>
> 2) Which buses go near my office? *- OK*
>
> 3) which buses are go near my office? *- wrong*

The meaning of those sentences is the same: *which bus routes are near your office*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which bus you can take, you might want to ask about bus stops near your office.
A bus might go by your office, but if there is no bus stop, you will never be able to get in said bus.

Which bus stops are near my office is what you want to ask

Comment: Thanks for answer Faurilldu Amandine. But is my sentence construction is correct? I want to ask someone, Which are the buses go to my office?

Comment: No, that construction isn't correct, there is either a word missing ("that" before "go") or "ing" at the end of go